# Class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext does not implement the requested interface org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, eclipse-plugin

When starting the Maven Project Wizard while having installed my own plug-in, leads to this error in the console and not starting the Wizard.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Class ch.qos.logback.classic.LoggerContext does not implement the requested interface org.slf4j.ILoggerFactory
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:270)
        at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:281)
        at org.eclipse.m2e.core.internal.MavenPluginActivator.<init>(MavenPluginActivator.java:87)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.loadBundleActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:758)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:711)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:932)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:309)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:581)
```

My research yielded in this having something to do with multiple bindings of different versions of slf4j jars? My plug-in is a maven project and the `pom.xml` contains the following items:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-slf4j-impl</artifactId>
    <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
```

Any thoughts why the error happens or is more information needed?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but perhaps this will help someone else as they try to resolve this issue.

The `IncompatibleClassChangeError` error is the result of SLF4J looking for an implementation to satisfy its API interface for `ILoggerFactory`.

Based on the provided pom.xml file, I'd guess `StaticLoggerBinder` in 'log4j-slf4j-impl' is attempting to use 'logback-classic' as the implementation.

You can try to use 'slf4j-simple' as the implementation for 'slf4j-api' to resolve the issue. However, slf4j-simple logs only to std error/out.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.10</version>
</dependency>
```